# Objects appear as black boxes when printing a PDF from Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, excel-2010

OK. Stackoverflow... i think this will be a tough nut to crack even for you!

I'm running Windows 7 with Office 2010. I've designed a Userform which users can fill out. The user form consists of a regular Worksheet, Formulas, and some Form Elements (not the active-x kind). All works well until I try to print it as a PDF. Then the Form Elements all appear as black boxes!

I'm using the Microsoft Office Native PDF printer and am required to do so (as i have some code that can be executed).

I've searched the net and only found two threads ([here](http://www.justanswer.com/microsoft-office/6uf3y-excel-2010-professional-prints-black-triangles-areas.html) and [here](http://communities.ptc.com/thread/13773)) in forums that even discuss the topic. Neither thread had useful answers. One thread claimed that the issue is with Excel (which i believe) and that it disappears with SP2. I have SP2 installed and that does not take care of the issue.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Black Boxes]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I experienced something similar before which may be the issue. Does this happen for all users, or just certan users? Because your userform is using Windows Theme colors, using certain themes can result in black blocks at printing... hooray. You may need to manually specify colors.

Comment: @DanielCook It happens for all users! In fact, that is how I first learned of the problem. A User wanted to print the document and ended up with the black boxes.

Comment: Does it happen when you print on "normal" printer?

Comment: @Voitcus It also happens on a regular printer!

Comment: There is option to mark fields while printing. That's why they are black. You should uncheck something in  options but I am writing this by phone and can't help more

Comment: @Voitcus You are probably mentioning the "Pring Object" check mark that is found in the objects Settings. Those are all checked.

Comment: Then consider also: 1. printing white-and-black, 2. print in low quality, 3. use system 3d acceleration. Does it happen also on print preview?

Comment: Please also make a new workbook (completely new) and see if this reproduces. If not, we would know it's the workbook problem, if yes, this might be Excel. You can also try to do the same with Word or Access, if you have them.

Answer (score 5):

I found that when this occurs, in some cases you can fix this by altering "Save As" options for the "PDF" type.

1. In the file "Save As" dialog, select PDF under "Save as type:"
2. Click on Options button
3. REMOVE the check from the "ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)" selection under PDF options (see image)

[image]

*Note:* I am using Excel 2010 v14.0.7153.5000, 64-bit running on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit OS, Service Pack 1

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that native pdf file converter only applies to Word or Excel documents per se. A Userform is neither.

Comment: Hi Gssi, as I tried to explain in the initial post, I created a Worksheet that is a Userform. To be clear, I did not go into the VBE and create a userform there... just a simply excel document that has some Form Elements in it! Hope that helps to clear it up. But interesting to learn that Userforms are not printed by the native PDF! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Microsoft word. May be updating your drivers solve your problem. Also bad font can raise this fault.